# How to correctly link page not folder with same name without .html extension

Tags: html

Maybe really dumb question but I'm building my first site

http://iservis.info/

Im trying to build classic URL structure

I have single page "Opravy" where all devices are listed and if you clicked on certain one i want to have URL "http://iservis.info/opravy/iphone-xs-max.

So on server i have a file "opravy.html" for main page and folder "Opravy" with all sub-pages with certain devices.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70KtL.png)

I also have .htaccess for all .html extensions

But problem is that in nav-bar I have nav-link "Opravy" and my code is like this

```
<a href="opravy" class="nav-menu-link--block desktop-only w-inline-block">
```

But its showing error because I think its trying to link the folder and not the "opravy.html" page.

So how do I link the "opravy.html" page to nav-link but without showing .html in URL ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use directory structure + `index.html`? Each index.html is rendered at the corresponding url that matches the directory structure. Something like this:

```
/ 
index.html
/../opravy
    index.html
/../../iphone-xs-max
       index.html
```

Comment: I dont rly get this :/ But every URL structure has something like www.domain.com/news/article ..

So whats the proper way to this ? I dont rly even know how to google this issue of mine

Comment: I only suggested this approach because it looks like the path you started on. If you type `yoursite.com/opravy` in your browser, the browser would render the `index.html` in the `/opravy` directory... and so on...